# Galaxy Nexus' Edit Text not full screen in landscape consistently

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-softkeyboard

In my application, I have a search button which when clicked will make an EditText widget visible, put focus in it, and show the keyboard.  When I do this I call this code:

```
queryTextView.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = Utilities.getInputMethodManagerFromContext(getContext());
    imm.showSoftInput(queryTextView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

The first time this shows as I expect it to in landscape:

[image: Working example]

Once I enter text and hit search, I will hide my EditText and force the keyboard closed.  I do this using this code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = Utilities.getInputMethodManagerFromContext(getContext());      
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
```

If I were to hit my button again to make the EdidText visible and show the keyboard again, my screen looks like this (only when using the stock Galaxy Nexus keyboard):

[image: Broken landscape]

Using another keyboard, such as SwiftKey, I do not get this behavior.  What kinds of things can I look for to find out why this soft-keyboard is not filling the screen fully?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: on second thought, from your screenshots it looks like the keyboard is trying to take up the full screen, so onEvaluateFullscreenMode should be returning true...perhaps the problem is somewhere in `onCreateExtractTextView`

Not what you're looking for, but if all else fails perhaps you could grap the AOSP keyboard source, walk through it and figure out if/why [onEvaluateFullscreenMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onEvaluateFullscreenMode%28%29) is returning, or maybe it isn't being called at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sam.  Unfortunately neither of these methods get called.  I put a breakpoint in both of these methods and when I invoke the keyboard neither of them get hit.  This was in the InputMethodService class of the AOSP source.  Is there another implementation that it could be using?  I didn't find any other matches greping through the AOSP source.

Comment: I think you want to be in the code for the keyboard itself, not the service that it extends. I did some more digging and found LatinIME.java (I tracked it down by looking at the running processes, and com.google.android.inputmethod.latin package led me to it) is where the code for the keyboard actually exists, which doesn't come with the source code that is downloaded by the Android SDK. Unfortunately unable to see any of the overrides I was talking about, although onStartInputView could be a place to look. http://bit.ly/JQRBrk

Comment: Weird the actual keyboard code isn't packaged with the AOSP.  I was able to get around this with the hacky solution of adding a new EditText to my decorView, giving that focus, calling hideSoftInputFromWindow, and then removing that textView.  Thanks for the response though, it's good to know some of these internal class names for the keyboard implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen" to achieve that feature.